# Ecommerce Application Cart Getting Empty after Logout

Tags: reactjs

I am new to react please help me guys. I am getting my cart empty after signout and I don't want it to happen I mean I don't want to make my cart empty automatically after signout I want all my items/products to be there right there in my cart even if I logout..!!
do I need to handle it from backend or else I can do it from frontend I am confused I am using react for the very first time so I am getting confused

**Index.js**

```
export const signout = (next) => {
const userId = isAuthenticated() && isAuthenticated().user.id;

console.log("USERID: ", userId);

if (typeof window !== undefined) {
  localStorage.removeItem("jwt");
  cartEmpty(() => {});
  //next();

  return fetch(`${API}user/logout/${userId}`, {
    method: "GET",
  })
    .then((response) => {
      console.log("Signout success");
      next();
    })
    .catch((err) => console.log(err));
}
```

};

**Cart.js**

```
export const addItemToCart = (item,next) => {
    let cart = [];
    if (typeof window !== undefined){
        if(localStorage.getItem("cart")){
            cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))
        }
        cart.push({
            ...item,
        });
        localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
        next();
    }
 }

export const loadCart =() => {
    if(typeof window !== undefined){
        if(localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
            return JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))    
        } 
    }
};

export const removeItemFromCart = (productId) => {
    let cart = [];
    if (typeof window !== undefined){
        if(localStorage.getItem("cart")) {
            cart = JSON.parse(localStorage.getItem("cart"))
        }
        cart.map((product, i) => {
            if(product.id === productId){
                cart.splice(i, 1)
            }
        });
        localStorage.setItem("cart",JSON.stringify(cart))
    } 
    return cart;
};

export const cartEmpty = (next) => {
    if (typeof window !== undefined){
        localStorage.removeItem("cart")
        let cart =[];
        localStorage.setItem("cart", JSON.stringify(cart));
        next();
    }
};
```

Comment: Have you tried ***not*** calling `cartEmpty(() => {});` in your signout function? What else can your code do as written? What have you tried different to not empty the cart unconditionally on logout?

Comment: django and python tag removed as this seems irrelevant

Comment: @DrewReese  if i will don't clear cart for the use that just signed out and if any another user sign  in with same browser window then those items could be accessible to that user also ... so that will not work.. any thing else suggestion from your side ..!! i just wanted my products be right there even if after logout

Comment: I see, so you want a cart associated to each user that logs in. Perhaps store a "user" object in localStorage with a cart array specific to them instead of just a single shared cart.

Comment: @Drew Reese ya ya that's my point and how to store the data in database... its getting stored in the local storage and that's may be the reason  when i logged out its getting empty ..!!! now i just want to stop my data to get empty .. !! going for cary_empy doesn't work any idea how to do it

Comment: Well, when a user logs in you could load (or generate) a localStorage cart using a user id as part of the key to set/get values from localStorage. When a user logs out don't call `cartEmpty` because this is what is clearing a cart on logout.